# What are the fastest tanks in diep.io?

Tags: diep.io

I just started playing [diep.io](https://diep.io) a few days ago, and I was wondering about the natural properties of the tanks offered in the game. Some tanks go faster due to recoil, and I'm interested in using a fast tank. Which tanks have more recoil in the game?

Answer (score 2):

Booster is the second fastest tank in the game, assuming you use max movement speed and max reload.

How to get to Booster: Basic -> Flank Guard -> Tri-Angle -> Booster. The tri-angle is the third-fastest tank in the game at level 30.

[image: what booster looks like]

Answer (score 2):

Annihilator has the most recoil per shot. How to get to Annihilator: Basic -> Machine Gun -> Destroyer -> Annihilator. The Destroyer is the fifth fastest tank at level 30.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to offer you a more complete answer than @Aedan and @Aka. Annihilator and Booster, respectively, are the two fastest tanks in the game. Assuming you max out the reload and movement speed, here are the fastest tanks in the game:

1. Annihilator
2. Booster
3. Triangle (at level 30 because lower level tanks are faster)
4. Fighter
5. Destroyer (at level 30)
6. Hybrid

The rest is history. If you don't believe me, [here is a diep.io sandbox test posted on YouTube proving my point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ugxybir0TsQ). It is a very common misconception that Booster is the fastest tank in the game. It is not, even though it might provide more continuous momentum unlike Annihilator, which provides momentum in bursts. Annihilator does have the [the most recoil per shot in diep.io.](https://diepio.fandom.com/Annihilator)